# In Kafka what happens to the record which takes more time than the max.poll.interval.ms

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

What happens to the long processing record when **max.poll.interval.ms** time exceeds  will it run in the background and rebalancing will be triggered .
As per my limited understanding the kafka consumer( Spring kafkalistener) service gets halted / restarted and the records get assigned to other consumers in the group during rebalancing

Answer (score 1):

You will have records left in memory being processed if the application or processing logic doesn't stop with the consumer thread.

If offsets were committed beforehand, those records would effectively be skipped after a rebalance. Otherwise, those offsets ideally shouldn't be committed post-processing since those records might be tried to be processed again, potentially resulting in data duplication, by other consumers after a rebalance.

Comment: Thanks   onecricketeer  for the clean explanation  . How to stop the consumer thread so that in memory records are not processed after the max time interval

Comment: The thread should already die after a rebalance. If you want to further halt your processing code, you'll probably need to set up the spring-kafka error handler classes such that the processing code knows if any error happened. I don't really have any examples